# Filtro WHERE baseado em lista com SQL

Tags: sql

Boa tarde!

Por favor, estou fazendo um filtro De Notas Fiscias baseado em uma série de CFOPs com SQL. Funciona assim:

```
SELECT * FROM NotasFiscais 
WHERE CFOP = 5101 OR CFOP = 6101 OR CFOP = 5922 OR CFOP = 6922 OR CFOP = 5933 CFOP = 6933 OR ....... CFOP = N
```

Como posso criar uma lista de CFOPs a serem passadas na cláusula WHERE pra meu código não ficar quilométrico?

Obs.: As CFOPs não seguem uma sequência lógica para usar um filtro do tipo >= Ou BETWEEN

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor, você quer apenas usar uma lista no where dentro do próprio sql ou existe uma aplicação que irá criar a query?

Comment: Dentro do próprio SQL mesmo

Comment: E os valores de CFOP vêm de onde? Você vai inseri-los na mão mesmo?

Comment: Sim, na unha. Não há uma regra (ainda) para a seleção das CFOPs, então vai na raça mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução viável é o uso da cláusula `IN`, onde ela irá trazer todos os resultados correspondentes as valores passados por parâmetro.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM NotasFiscais
WHERE CFOP IN('5101', '6101', ...)
```

EDIT: Para pesquisar em campo varchar, basta envolver os valores com apóstrofos.

Segue [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177682.aspx).

Comment: Cara, perfeito.
Funcionou mesmo com o campo no formato VARCHAR. Não conhecia a cláusula IN.

Obrigado!